# How to configure github webhook to Jenkins servers behind Google's Cloud IAP

Tags: jenkins, github, google-iap

Currently having Jenkins servers behind Google Cloud IAP (https://cloud.google.com/iap/) handling authentication and using Jenking GitHub plugin. How do I configure GitHub webhook to work with Google Cloud IAP? Whatever I configure in the webhook, I get

```
Headers
Alt-Svc: clear
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 18:09:49 GMT
X-Goog-IAP-Generated-Response: true
Body
There was a problem with your request. Error code 13
```

from Cloug IAP. Any suggestions on what exactly to put in the webhook config page?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) the load-balancer firewall should allow bypassing the IAP and enable direct access, but it didn't work for me.
I also tried to add the ranges of GitHub in GSuite role (in the [context-aware access](https://admin.google.com/ac/security/context-aware) but couldn't add it to the role).

I suggest creating a new load-balancer with a dedicated URL just for GitHub hooks and configure the firewall to allow the hooks access - found [here](https://api.github.com/meta) but rarely changed:
 "hooks": [
    "192.30.252.0/22",
    "185.199.108.0/22",
    "140.82.112.0/20"
  ]

edit: 
I've ended up using smee.io to bypass the IAP as it's configured on the backend - so the extra frontend/load balancer didn't help :(